# Predicting Averaged Dependent Variable with Individual, Independent Variables

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, mixed-model, biostatistics

I am trying to predict the quantity of a compound that cells produce under different growth durations, via image-extracted features. I am able to extra unique cell-specific features, but can only calculate the concentration of compound for all cells (an average concentration). Am I able to use this bulk concentration as a dependent variable with some algorithm (such as multiple regression), although all the independent variables are unique?

Alternatively, I can use the growth duration as a predicted dependent variable, but is less interesting than predicting the compound concentration, and I do not want incorporate it as an independent variable.

I think I might need to use a mixed model with random effects, but am unsure. I am also open to another model, if multiple regression does not seem appropriate for this situation.

Here is some sample, made-up data:

```
Shape1    Shape2    Area1    AvgIntensity    Duration    BulkConcentration
0.98      1.6       30.1     1128            30 min      2.1
0.48      1.0       40.6     1138            30 min      2.1
0.28      2.1       50.3     198             30 min      2.1
0.08      1.3       70.7     1098            30 min      2.1
0.92      5.6       90.2     1128            60 min      2.5
0.76      2.6       10.0     1298            60 min      2.5
0.35      7.4       40.1     1698            60 min      2.5
0.99      4.2       60.5     1178            60 min      2.5
0.28      9.3       30.3     1098            90 min      2.6
0.28      9.3       50.8     1298            90 min      2.6
0.28      9.3       40.1     1898            90 min      2.6
0.28      9.3       80.5     1998            90 min      2.6
```